# how to forward traffic to ipsec vpn tunnel created using openswan?

Tags: centos, networking, vpn, nat, openswan

I want to forward traffic to ipsec vpn tunnel created by openswan.
I searched the internet but i couldn't find the solution. check below :-

1- VPN tunnel is created and it's name is demo-connection-vpn.
2- I need to forward all traffic that destination is 185.127.140.1 to vpn tunnel.

Check my below `ipsec.conf` file

```
    config setup
    plutodebug=all
    plutostderrlog=/var/log/pluto.log
    protostack=netkey
    nat_traversal=yes
    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12

    oe=off

    conn demo-connection-vpn
    authby=secret
    auto=start
    ike=AES128-SHA1

    ## phase 1 ##
    keyexchange=ike
    aggrmode=no
    ikelifetime=86400s

    ## phase 2 ##
    phase2=esp
    phase2alg=aes128
    ikelifetime=86400s
    compress=no
    pfs=no
    type=tunnel
    left=208.109.152.48
    leftsourceip=208.109.152.48
    leftsubnet=208.109.152.48/32
    right=185.127.140.32
    rightsubnet=185.127.140.0/27
```